# when casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity

Tags: c#

I just want to round the value which comes from datatable,Data comes from SQL to datable.Also datatable have null values i guess this the problem but please also you check for me

```
string Maxmonthlytable = Math.Round((decimal)monthlytable.Rows[u][3], 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
```

I get the error " when casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity "

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636986/when-casting-from-a-number-the-value-must-be-a-number-less-than-infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
decimal num = 0;
if (monthlytable.Rows[u][3] != DBNull.Value)
    num = Math.Round((decimal)monthlytable.Rows[u][3], 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
string Maxmonthlytable = num.ToString();
```

Comment: throw the same exception for num.What can i do?

Comment: even the value is not null i have the same exception.Can you please help

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method which supports [nullables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

```
decimal? num = monthlytable.Rows[u].Field<decimal?>(3);
Console.Write(num.HasValue 
                 ? Math.Round(num.Value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                 : "no value");
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the cast `(decimal)` or using the cast `(int)`, you have to use the cast `(System.Decimal)` or `(System.Int32)` and that will make this problem go away.

Comment: `decimal` and `int` are an aliases for `System.Decimal` and `System.Int32`, respectively. They will behave identical in all respects. [According to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(v=vs.80).aspx), "The C# type keywords and their aliases are interchangeable."